# Suspend on exceptions caused inside Django app in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, exception, pycharm

I debug django application and want to suspend code execution at the point where exception occurs with cursor pointing to problematic place in code. Pretty HTML display by django would be helpful either but not mandatory. My IDE is PyCharm.

If I set pycharm to suspend on termination of exception, then I never catch it, because django handles the exception with HTML debug info and exceptions never terminate. Setting DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True inside settings.py causes HTML debug info to disappear but the execution does not terminate either.

If I set pycharm to suspend on raise of exception, then I have to pass all existing exceptions inside py internals such as copy.py, decimal.py, gettext.py, etc, which is inconvenient (there are so many of them that I could never reach exceptions caused by my code).

If I set "temporary" setup to suspend on raise of exception which occurs after given breakpoint (which I place at the last line of settings.py) then django server does not start.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically in PyCharm. What you need to do is set no breakpoints, but run as debug (click on the green bug icon). When the exception occurs, execution should automatically halt.

Comment: not work, run as debug and make sure `Any Exception` -> `On termination` checked. `Django` handled exceptions by it self and auto restart, `termination` seems not reached.